# Need to get the values of the objects (JSON) which have been created dynamically

Tags: object, dynamic, pentaho

How to get the top object value in PentahoDI? I have got the other elements like Category, Subcategory, section from the following example of Json file. However, I need to capture the first root object which is `x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b` and `x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b`

```
{
    "x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b": {
        "Category": "chapter", 
        "SubCategory": [
            "x@4eb9072cf36f4d6fa1e98717e6bb54f7", 
            "x@d85849fbde324690b6067f3b18c4258d", 
            "x@3edff1a1864f41fe8b212df2bc96bf13"
        ], 
        "Section": {
            "display_name": "Week 1 Section"
        }
    }, 
    "x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b": {
        "category": "course", 
        "Subcategory": [
            "x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b"
        ], 
        "Section": {
            "advanced_modules": [
                "google-document"
            ], 
        }
    }
}
```

In the Fields tab of the Json Input step I have given the Names and Paths as: Category --> $..Category, Subcategory --> $..Subcategory, Section --> $..Section.

However, I am unable to get the root element as it is crucial information for us to work on it. ex (`x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b` and `x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b`)

I have used the following code to get the values of the dynamic objects but it didnt work. The following is the code I used it.

```
var obj = JSON.parse (JBlock) //Jblock is the one which holds the entire string.
var keys = Object.name( obj);
```

Comment: Is it something specific to Pentaho or not? If not, what the programming language is used?

Comment: Have you tried using the various Object methods? Object.keys()? Are those available to you?

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this guys. I am trying to do this in Pentaho but since the Object is not recognised in Json I am unable to get the value. @Mikanikal - I have used Object.keys() but I am getting Category, Subcategory and Section BUT NOT THE TOP ELEMENT which is the main identifier for my requirement. ("x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b": and "x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b":). As this is unnamed object/key/array I am unable to proceed anything on this. Could someone help? Thanks

Comment: I went thru many searches and in many forums but I am unable to find any solution to retrieve this Unnamed element in the JSON file which is very crucial bit for me to proceed.

I would like to mention an example here again maybe in a simpler way.

{
"object1" {
"Category": "chapter", 
"SubCategory": [ "Subcategoryvalues1", "subcategoryvalues2"], 
"Section": {"display_name": "Week 1 Section"}}, 
"object2": {
"category": "course", 
"Subcategory": ["subcategory1"], 
"Section": {"advanced_modules": ["google-document"], }}
}

Comment: This is how exactly my Json files arrives and I am populating into the table. Because of the object1 and object2 created dynamically I am unable to fetch the value. I can get the values of category, subcategory and section by giving the path $..category, $.subcategory and $.section to get those values. 

How do I get the Pentaho or Javascript to fetch the value Object1 and object2 into some variables /columns.

I am really struggling to get any output thou I have spend huge amount of time working on this.

Could somebodyplease help?

Answer (score 0):

1. JSONPath is not able to get the keys of a JSON structure. This is one of my main issues with JSONPath, and I wish Pentaho had included other JSON parsing engines.
2. This JavaScript to be used in `Modified Java Script Value` works for me. Add a value in the fields editor like this:

[image]

And then a script like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JBlock);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
    var idx = getInputRowMeta().size();
    row[idx++] = keys[i];
    putRow(row);
}
trans_Status = SKIP_TRANSFORMATION;
```

Comment: Hi Bolav, Thank you for your reply. I am getting the child elements only and not the name of the object. I am getting elements like Category, Subcategory and Section but not the object values. Is there any way to iterate those? Thanks

Comment: @Dubbu: The code that I pasted gives two lines, one with `main_key` x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4bm and one with `main_key` x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b, when I test it.

Comment: Hi Bolav, Thank you very much for your reply. I have noticed that I am getting output if I use the above data in a constant data step whereas if I am using a Json file using Json File Input step and sending the Json data using JBlock,path as $..* and dattype as String, it is throwing an error (using the same code in MJSV step) saying SyntaxError: Unexpected token: v (script#1) (which is the start of the line) I am confused and tbh struggling to finish this task. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: What I meant above is if I copy the Json file as a string in DataGrid and pass that value to MJSV then it works well but if I point to a json file as a source then I am not getting the require output. Is there any difference between getting a JSON file into a string and defining the json value as a string in Data Grid. Could you please explain if possible? Thanks, Dubbu

Comment: You need to get the complete JSON to a JBlock for this solution to work. If the primary target is to get the main keys I don't think you should use the JSON Input step. Anyway the JSON Input step can take the JSON from a String field as well.

Comment: Hi, I know its really a long time to come back on this as I thought I have sorted with you guys help, but turns out the value is incorrect. ie. x@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4b has been populated for these keys  "Category": "chapter", 
        "SubCategory": [
            "x@4eb9072cf36f4d6fa1e98717e6bb54f7", 
            "x@d85849fbde324690b6067f3b18c4258d", 
            "x@3edff1a1864f41fe8b212df2bc96bf13"
        ], 
        "Section": {
            "display_name": "Week 1 Section"
        }
    }, rather than x@chapter@e50de0196d77495d9b50fc05567b4a4bm

Comment: Ideally the key value is the top one and it has got child elements : "Category": "chapter", 
        "SubCategory": [
            "x@4eb9072cf36f4d6fa1e98717e6bb54f7", 
            "x@d85849fbde324690b6067f3b18c4258d", 
            "x@3edff1a1864f41fe8b212df2bc96bf13"
        ], 
        "Section": {
            "display_name": "Week 1 Section"
        }.... but it picks up the next line which is a key for the next set of objects....  Thank you guys for your help...